# Proof for a periodic function

Tags: problem-solving, periodic-functions

I have to solve the following exercise:

The function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a periodic function with $P = 2\pi$ so that $f(x) = f(x + 2\pi)$ is true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that there is a $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(\xi) = f(\xi + \pi)$.

Either I don't understand the exercise or the exercise doesn't make sense. Sure, for $f(x) = sin(x)$ for example there is a $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$. But not all periodic functions have a $\xi$.

For example the function $f(x) = mod(x,2\pi)$ don't have a $\xi$.

Am I right or did I understand something wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the exercise should also assume that $f$ is continuous. Without it, this is indeed incorrect.

Comment: I also thought that, but the exercise doesn't assume that $f$ has to be continuous. I will ask my prof on monday. Maybe he made a mistake.